# Programmatically access web-page

Tags: java, html, parsing

There is a website that displays results after entering a roll number and clicking the submit button. I need to programmatically access results of some available roll number.

The HTML code for the foam is:

```
<form action="http://www.rtuportal.com/result/65-b-tech-ivth-sem-main-exam-result-2013/" method="post">
    <input type="" name="roll_number" value="" placeholder="enter your roll number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form><div style="margin-top: 30px;"><div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.rtuportal.com/result/65-b-tech-ivth-sem-main-exam-result-2013/" data-width="730" data-num-posts="10"></div></div>
```

1. Is the roll number to be sent to the URL mentioned in `action` attribute of `form` tag?
2. What data needs to be sent and how should I format it?

I'll be doing this in Java using jsoup.

UPDATE: I'm able to get the URL where result data is present, but when I connect to it with jsoup, I get "an error occurred" but when I visit the same url through a browser, the result is displayed correctly. Do I need something to make this jsoup request look like a browser request?  I'm already using Mozilla as the UA.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. The form is using the post method. Take a look at this code. It opens the result page as Mozilla Firefox. The Variable with the name definied in the `<input type="" name="roll_number"` is passed onto the page with the `data()` Method.

Code formatting doesnt work right

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url")
.data("roll_number", "yourValue")
.userAgent("Mozilla")
.post();
```

Comment: This didn't work. The receiver HTML code doesn't contain any result data. If I save the code as HTML file and disconnect the Internet, the browser just displays the error message "Server not found" at the lace of result. The page still gets the result data from the server after opening the received HTML page.

Comment: UPDATE: from the result page's code, the data is contained in an iframe that fetches the result from a URL and sends a key along with the roll number.